# Why does $\sum_p \sum_{k \geq 2} \frac{1}{kp^{ks}} \leq \frac{1}{2} \sum_p \sum_{k \geq 2} \frac{1}{p^{k}}$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

In his short [note](http://pollack.uga.edu/eulerprime.pdf) on Euler and the prime harmonic series, Professor of Mathematics Paul Pollack, uses the following step without explanation other than $s>1$.

$$
\sum_p \sum_{k \geq 2} \frac{1}{kp^{ks}} \leq \frac{1}{2} \sum_p \sum_{k \geq 2} \frac{1}{p^{k}}
$$

I understand that $\frac{1}{kx^s} < \frac{1}{x}$ if $s>1$ and $k>1$, but ..

**Q1.** I don't understand where the $\frac{1}{2}$ comes from.

**Q2.** I don't understand why the inequality is $\leq$ and not $<$.

I would appreciate any help. I am not a trained mathematician so avoiding technical terms would be a bonus.

Comment: I believe it just follows from $kp^{ks}\ge 2p^k$. (Note $k\ge 2$). As for $\le$ vs. $\lt$, maybe they did not care: $\le$ is weaker and follows from $\lt$, but, maybe, for the following arguments it is just sufficient to use this weaker statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $k\geqslant 2$, we have $\frac{1}{kp^{ks}}\leqslant\frac{1}{2p^{ks}}$ and for $s>1$ we have $\frac{1}{p^{ks}}<\frac{1}{p^k}$ so we have $\frac{1}{kp^{ks}}<\frac{1}{2p^s}$. The inequality is $<$ so it is also $\leqslant$, it seems that the weaker inequality $\leqslant$ is sufficient to prove what the note wants to prove.